# Where can I find my .emacs file for Emacs on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, emacs

I am trying to install [Proof General](https://proofgeneral.github.io/) (A generic Emacs interface for proof assistants), and it's saying add some lines in your `.emacs` file but I am not able to find `.emacs` file on my system.

Comment: The default location is `~/.emacs` AFAIK; if no such file exists, just go ahead and create one

Answer (score 0):

As @steeldriver already mentioned, the `.emacs` config file usually resides in your home directory. See also [The Emacs Initialization File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File).

If you need to start with a blank `.emacs`, try `touch ~/.emacs` and then open it with your editor of choice (that I'm guessing is not Emacs) to add the requested lines.

And if you have further questions on emacs, [Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) is probably the best place to ask.